# how to set a different message for an email template in odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I created a custom module and had used the calendar object to create an event and the code is as follows

```
def create_calender_event(self,cr,uid,ids,context=None):
    calendar_obj = self.pool.get('calendar.event')      
    for rec in self.browse(cr,uid,ids,context=context):
        if rec.action:
            for rec_res in rec.action:
                calendar_obj.create(cr,uid,{'name' : rec_res.act_ion,
                    'user_id' : rec_res.asgnd_to.id,
                    'start_date' : rec_res.due_date,
                    'stop_date' : rec_res.due_date,
                    'allday' : True,
                    'partner_ids' : [(6,0, [rec_res.asgnd_to.partner_id.id])]
                },context=context)
```

This will create a event in respective user's calendar, but it uses default template message.

How can i replace the calendar invitation template message by custom message ?

Comment: How can i replace the template message only for my custom module without affecting the original email template used for calendar event invitation ?

Comment: not bad, no one has the answer... lol

Answer (score 3):

you can do like this from py file

1) get the template_id and browse the object 
2) the template body will be stored in 'body_html' field
3) store the body_html field in one variable, lets say: **old_body** 
4) then add your customized code to template's 'body_html' field and write the values into template using the above temlate_id 
5) send the mail, using send method 
6) then write back the **old_body** value back to the template.

just for idea, refer this....

template_id = template_pool.search(cr,uid,[('name','=ilike',template_name)])
                if template_id:
                    template_obj = template_pool.browse(cr, uid, template_id)
                    body = template_obj.body_html
                    body_old = body
                    count = 0 
                    body += "

For  **%s Study Notes PDF**   Click here

"%(url['subject'],url['url'])
                    template_pool.write(cr, uid, template_id, {'body_html':body})
                    template_pool.send_mail(cr, uid, template_id[0], record.id)
                    template_pool.write(cr, uid, template_id, {'body_html': 
body_old})

Comment: Thank you shravan, i will try with your idea too ASAP... i am working on one more issue

Comment: Shravan do I need to pass any template xml id as argument ? How the function header would look like and how the function would be called ?

Comment: include template_pool = self.pool.get('email.template') and template name is not xml-id, just pass the name of the template

Comment: Yes shravan, included it before itself but error is same though

Comment: Shravan I need to write it within the above function itself right ?

Comment: yes, can you post your code. Also above i have provided like pseudocode. So, modify it according to your requirement

Comment: I am a newbie so had the confusion. anyways thanks a lot.

Comment: what is the url part in the pseudocode you suggested ?

Comment: exclude the url part,

Answer (score 0):

It's email template with xml id "calendar_template_meeting_invitation" is used to send invitation. So find this template and change to whatever you want. Under template its called "Meeting Invitation" email template.

OLD===================

UPDATES================================

on `calendar.event`  object  `create` and `write` method calls the method `create_attendees` which create all attendee and  send email invitation by calling method `_send_mail_to_attendees` [code ref](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/calendar/calendar.py#L1116), so you need to overload that function and remvoe that statement so it doesn't send email when attendee is created rather send invitation when you want.

Bests

Comment: Thanks firebug,,Yes doing so will change the original template itself, i want that template to  get changed only when the above code is executed..

Comment: Check Reply body added more details

Comment: Thanks Firebug for your answers, i will try on that.