# How can I override this method in odoo?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I had used the following code to create a calendar event from my custom module.

```
def create_calender_event(self,cr,uid,ids,context=None):
    calendar_obj = self.pool.get('calendar.event')      
    for rec in self.browse(cr,uid,ids,context=context):
        if rec.action:
            for rec_res in rec.action:
                calendar_obj.create(cr,uid,{'name' : rec_res.act_ion,
                    'user_id' : rec_res.asgnd_to.id,
                    'start_date' : fields.date.today(),
                    'stop_date' : rec_res.due_date,
                    'allday' : True,
                    'partner_ids' : [(6,0, [rec_res.asgnd_to.partner_id.id])]
                },context=context)
    return True
```

Calendar event object uses the following function

```
def _send_mail_to_attendees(self, cr, uid, ids, email_from=tools.config.get('email_from', False),template_xmlid='calendar_template_meeting_invitation', force=False, context=None):
```

I want to know if I can override this method and set my custom email template in my code above so that email sent during creation of an calendar event would send out my custom email template message

Answer (score 0):

You can manage this setting a variable in the context. In Odoo 8, you can modify the context this way (you have to write this inside **the function which calls the** `_send_mail_to_attendees` method -it could be one of these: `do_mail_reminder`, `create_attendees`, `do_sendmail` or the `write` method of the class `calendar_event`-):

```
context.update({
    'set_my_template': True,
    'my_template_xml_id': 'your_module.your_template_xml_id',
})
```

Once you located the function which makes the call and added to it the peace of code I wrote just above, you must overwrite `def _send_mail_to_attendees` this way:

```
def _send_mail_to_attendees(
   self, cr, uid, ids, email_from=tools.config.get('email_from', False),
   template_xmlid='calendar_template_meeting_invitation',
   force=False, context=None):
    if context.get('set_my_template', False):
        template_xmlid = context.get('my_template_xml_id', False)
    result = super(calendar_attendee, self)._send_mail_to_attendees(
        cr, uid, ids, email_from, template_xmlid, force, context)
```

Comment: Forvas thanks a lot for your answer. Unfortunately I am getting this error AttributeError: 'mom.meeting' object has no attribute 'env'

Comment: The function `_send_mail_to_attendees` is inside the class `calendar.attendee`, isn't it? And the function `create_calender_event` is inside a class you have created. Is `mom.meeting` the name of this class? (I mean, is your function `create_calender_event` inside the class `mom.meeting`)

Comment: yes it is inside the class, no problems on that. Does replacing env with ._context would solve the problem ? (Actually I already changed from env to ._context)

Comment: `._context` is a shortcut, so it should be the same. I'm sorry, the code of the function is version 7, I didn't realize that. I'm going to edit my answer, take a look at that.

Comment: thats ok, Actually I am kindoff trying to implement on V8 also sometimes v7. I will try on with it now. Thank you very much :)

Comment: forvas, this wont work according to my above requirement ?

Comment: I have just realized that `create_calender_event` doesn't call directly the `_send_mail_to_attendees`. I'm going to edit the answer.

Comment: forvas can you just have a look at my another similar question which I had posted. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31446205/how-to-set-a-different-message-for-an-email-template-in-odoo/31678692?noredirect=1#comment52160692_31678692

Comment: Check for the code uploaded by Shravan which is upvoted. what you have got to say on that answer ?

Comment: The only way is to set the template message only when the above function is executed right forvas and then set it back to the old body